# On ubuntu, run "python randomTrips.py" -n xxx.net.xml -r xxxx.rou.xml -e 2000 -l" command, an error exist

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, sumo, flow-project

My ubuntu system is 18.04.
Anaconda version:anaconda Command line client (version 1.7.2)

I can run "python randomTrips.py" command on my Windows,
Then I copy the randomTrip.py file into my ubuntu system,
And ran again, there is an error:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "randomTrips.py", line 523, in <module>
    if not main(get_options()):
  File "randomTrips.py", line 498, in main
    subprocess.call(args2)
  File "/home/dnl/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 247, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/home/dnl/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/home/dnl/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1289, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'duarouterD'
```

Why? Are there any methods?

Comment: What is the `randomTrips.py` file?

Comment: Can you do `print(args2)` just before `subprocess.call(args2)` and tell us the result?

Comment: The args2 is: args2  ['duarouterD', '-n', 'changsha.net.xml', '-r', 'trips.trips.xml', '--ignore-errors', '--begin', '0', '--end', '2000.0', '--no-step-log', '--no-warnings', '-o', 'changsha.rou.xml']

Comment: the introduction url to randomTrips is that: https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tools/Trip

Comment: Well I don't know what duarouter is but you probably have to install it on Linux as well. Windows could file the `duarouterD`, but Linux can't so you probably don't have that installed, or not specified in your PATH variable (Google that if you don't know what it is!)

Comment: Well,because I followed the install instruction on the website of flow, and test it which is no problem.  Is there any difference between : sumo binaries (installed by following scripts/setup_sumo_ubuntu1804.sh)  and sumo(installed from the official website fo sumo).?? and i checked the contents of sumo_binaries there are just few things. So your advice is I need to install sumo from the official website of sumo? @nathanlct

Comment: There are some codes from randomTrips.py: import sumolib  # noqa
from sumolib.miscutils import euclidean  # noqa
DUAROUTER = sumolib.checkBinary('duarouter')    So I searched the 'sumolib' on my computer, i can find it on that directory:/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sumolib. It is looks strange, I cannot understand it. @nathanlct

Comment: Ok, I installed sumo again, from the flow website, i followed the "Direct install of SUMO from GitHub", and the path is no problem, i still face the same problems:FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'duarouterD': 'duarouterD